# How to reserve the original variants while upgrading a port in MacPorts?

Tags: macos, port, macports

When I upgrade some ports, I notice the upgraded port might change its variants. Is it normal or my mis-observation?

Let's say the original variants for git-core is +bash_completion +doc +python26 +svn, but if I just do **sudo port upgrade git-core**, it would change to +bash_completion +doc +python27! And that would force the installation of python27! How could I prevent this issue happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are correct, variants can change.

As git-core now has the default variants +python27 (among others) you have 3 options:

- Live with it
- Upgrade it by hand
- Set default variants in ${PREFIX}/etc/macports/variants.conf to the things you like.

Hope this helps :)